# Debuging JBoss Fuse 6.3 with Red Hat JBoss 11.1.0 Developer Studio error

Tags: jboss, jbossfuse

This message is appearing when I try to debug in Jboss Developer Studio 11.1.0. My debug port is 5005 in server and I also add it to debug config as port.

> Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused. Connection
>   refused: connect

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason you changed the default debug port?  I've never touched JBoss Fuse, but I did have Red Hat JBoss Developer Studio 10.1.0 installed.  I downloaded JBoss Fuse 6.3, added it as a server in the IDE.  Did the [sample project](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.3/pdf/developing_and_deploying_applications/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse-6.3-Developing_and_Deploying_Applications-en-US.pdf) maven install, deployed the application in Fuse.  Set a break point and the debugger stopped right where it was supposed to - maybe try undoing your port changes?

Comment: ok .thank you problem solved. there was some issue with my port

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could help